# libsvm on linux - how to add path

Tags: python, ubuntu, libsvm

I downloaded the tar file for libsvm, navigated to the python directory and ran the make command. This words and when I run python inside that same directory,

```
import svm
```

works just fine. But not in any other directory. What can I do to make this library accessible from any where? I know it has some thing to do with copying the path some where, but not sure since I'm a newbie at linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what linux distro are you on? on my Ubunto I just:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-libsvm
```

...

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:03:06) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import svm
>>> 
$ cd /tmp
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:03:06) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import svm
>>>
```

Comment: Is it available for Python3.x versions?